# Queue sorting function sorts to the wrong queue

Tags: c, sorting, struct, queue

Here is my queue sorting function, where dispatchlist, realtime, and jobqueue are all defined as a queue struct

```
struct Queue {
  pcbptr front;
  pcbptr back;
};
typedef struct Queue queue;
```

and pcbptr is defined as

```
struct PCB {
int pid;                        
int arrival_time;   
int time_left;
int priority;
int status;                     
int printers;
int modems;
int scanners;
int cds;
int memory;         //might need a struct for memory block?
struct PCB* next;
struct PCB* prev;
};
typedef struct PCB pcb;
typedef pcb * pcbptr;
```

Now the actual function

```
void starthostd(){
  int i=0;
  while(dispatchlist.front != NULL){
    if(dispatchlist.front->priority == 0){
        enqueue(dispatchlist.front, &realtime);
        dispatchlist.front = dispatchlist.front->next;
        printf("the %d pcb was moved to realtime queue\n", i );
    }
    else{
        enqueue(dispatchlist.front, &jobqueue);
        dispatchlist.front = dispatchlist.front->next;
        printf("the %d pcb was moved to job queue\n", i );
    }
    i++;
  }
  while(realtime.front != NULL){
    printf("blah");
    realtime.front = realtime.front->next;
  }
}
```

And here is my implementation of enqueue

```
void enqueue( pcbptr mypcb, queue* queue) {
  if (queue->front == NULL){ //empty
        queue->front = mypcb;
  }
  else{
    queue->back->next = mypcb; 
  }
  queue->back = mypcb; //set this pcb to the end of the queue
}
```

Basically I have 7 pcbptr originally in dispatchlist, the first 4 have priority 1, the 5th has priority 0, and the last 2 have priority 1.

So what should happen is that pcbs 1,2,3,4,6,7 should be moved to jobqueue, and pcb 5 should be moved to realtime.

When I run the program, the proper print lines are printed, so this is output, which is expected:

```
the 0 pcb was moved to job queue
the 1 pcb was moved to job queue
the 2 pcb was moved to job queue
the 3 pcb was moved to job queue
the 4 pcb was moved to realtime queue
the 5 pcb was moved to job queue 
the 6 pcb was moved to job queue
```

(i know that the numbers in the statement above is behind by 1)

But however, the expected result should be that blah is printed just once, since there is only one pcb in the realtime queue. However, it is printed 3 times, for pcbs 5,6,7.

To me it seems like once one pcb is moved into the realtime queue, every other element is also moved into realtime queue as well, even though it is not supposed to.

Can anyone spot what i might be missing?

Thanks

PS: I have a side question, I inserted a usleep(5000) into the while loop that prints the "blah", but it does not seem to delay the prints at all, what might be the cause of that?

Comment: Concerning side question:  Cause output to _flush_ .  Try adding `'\n'` to `printf("blah\n");`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how you move elements from one queue to another. You insert `mypcb` in the queue, but don't take into account other elements linked with it. So you have original list

```
job:      1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
realtime:
```

Then you want to move fifth element between queues, but you don't change links between nodes, and so you've got something like this

```
job:      1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7
realtime: 5 -> 6 -> 7
```

To solve this you need to change links in the queue, I guess this will work

```
if(dispatchlist.front->priority == 0){
    pcbptr t = dispatchlist.front;
    dispatchlist.front = dispatchlist.front->next;
    t->next = NULL;
    enqueue(t, &realtime);
    printf("the %d pcb was moved to realtime queue\n", i );
}
```